# Webpack config in React app using ModuleFederation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have a question regarding Webpack config. If a React app is created using CRA and I want to implement Microfrontend using ModuleFederationPlugin, is it necessary to define all the things in the webpack config e.g. I see htmlPlugin, module.rules?

Are the above configs necessary to be explicitly added to webpack config OR can I somehow just specify configurations related to ModuleFederationPlugin?

```
const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./public/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
}); // IS THIS REQUIRED TO BE SPECIFIED ?
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    port: 3000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{// IS THIS REQUIRED TO BE SPECIFIED ?
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: "babel-loader"
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    htmlPlugin,
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "MicroFrontend",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Button": "./src/Button"
      },
      shared: { react: { singleton: true, eager: true }, "react-dom": { singleton: true, eager: true } },
    })
  ]
};
```

In short, I am just trying to understand what is the bare minimum config I need to specify for incorporating ModuleFederationPlugin